# How to move scroll bar to a certain place by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list in item, with a scroll bar. Also there is a button. So when the button is pressed, the scroll moves to the given id to make it visible. I looked at similar solution, but could not make mine working.

Here is my code:

```
function next() {
    $("#example").css("background", "red");
}

function goToByScroll(id) {
    // Reove "link" from the ID
    // Scroll
    $('ul').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top()
    },
        'slow');
}

$("button").click(function (e) {
    // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    // Call the scroll function
    goToByScroll("example");
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Name1</li>
    <li>Name2</li>
    <li>Name3</li>
    <li>Name4</li>
    <li>Name5</li>
    <li>Name6</li>
    <li>Name7</li>
    <li id="example">Name8</li>
    <li>Name9</li>
    <li>Name10</li>
</ul>
<button onClick="next()">Next</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danials/f2UZT/
Any idea to make it working? It must work as a function, so the function value will be an id, so it moves to the element holding the id.

Comment: instead of `offset().top()` use `offset().top`, just remove `()` from `top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top()`

Use this

`scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top`

and to avoid `li` to go upward use `li` height, 
so your final code would be

```
$('ul').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top - $("#" + id).height()
},'slow');
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f2UZT/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its working. But it's not very accurate. Is there anyway to make it accurate. I tried different classes, and sometimes it finds the class but scroll to a bit upper or lower than the element, so the element goes out of the box. Anyway idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for scrolling

```
$.fn.scrollView = function () {
  return this.each(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
   }, 1000);
 });
}
```

And for target button and target position

```
$('#post-1').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#contact').scrollView();
});
```